# Arrays in enums in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

Currently my C++ code is:

```
constexpr struct my_codes {
    std::array<int, other_class1::static_constans1> num1 = {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};
    std::array<int, other_class2::staric_constans2> num2 = {{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}};
    int num3 = 15;
} my_codes;
```

Obviously I feel bad about this, and it is getting out of hand (I have the first 100 numbers typed out). Sadly, these enums are illegal:

```
enum my_codes {
    num1[other_class1::static_constans1], 
    num2[other_class2::staric_constans2], 
    num3
};
enum my_codes {num1[7], num2[8], num3};
```

Can I have arrays in enums by some magic? Any macros I can use? Some recursive templating?

Edit:
I would use it like:

```
enum my_codes {num1[7], num2[8], num[3]};
if (some_int == my_codes::num2[3]) do_somethig();
```

The enum would have these values:

```
my_codes::num1[0] == 0
my_codes::num1[1] == 1
...
my_codes::num1[6] == 6
my_codes::num2[0] == 7
my_codes::num2[1] == 8
...
my_codes::num2[7] == 14
my_codes::num3    == 15
```

Comment: "Obviously I feel bad about this" well... *obviously*, but still... humor me, what is wrong with that?

Comment: There's probably a way to set up something so you can use certain names *as though* there were an enum defined that way. So how exactly would you like the code using these to look?

Comment: Can you explain what "arrays in enums" mean to you?

Comment: Can you provide some code that would actually use this so we know what you're trying to do?

Comment: What's the connection between a struct and an enum ? Can't figure out what you are trying to do. Maybe it's worth explaining...

Comment: Why do you want to have this? What is your actual use case?

Answer (score 2):

Since your constants are contiguous, you don't need the array - a range check operation is sufficient. That is to say, since `num1` contains `[0, 7)` and `num2` contains `[7, 15)`, your struct can be expressed as

```
 constexpr struct my_codes {
     std::array<int,4> num = {{0,7,14,15}}
 } mycodes;

 constexpr int getIndex(int i, int offset = 0) {
    return (offset==3 || i < mycodes.num[offset+1]) ?
    offset :
    getIndex(i, offset+1) ;
 }
```

which is just a recursive way to write a linear search through a `constexpr` array. Generating the i'th range is even simpler, that's just `num[i]` up to `num[i+1]`.